# 3 divs changing location based on screen size

Tags: html, css

I would like to have 3 divs that normally are shown in the page like below

```
--------------
|     |      |
|  1  |      |
|     |   2  |
|-----|      |
|     |      |
|  3  |      |
|     |      |
--------------
```

so html will be something like

> **EDIT**: I do think there is a better solution but to keep 1 and 3 on the
>   left one after the other first thing you may do is placing them inside
>   another div.
>
> I do believe that doing so it will be impossible to solve the resize
>   by the use of media queries only.
>
> Is there a way to achieve the same visual result without the external container div?

```
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                <div>
                    <div id="1" class="main-content-left float-left">
                        @RenderSection("leftBefore", required: false)
                    </div>
                    <div id="3" class="main-content-left-after float-left">
                        @RenderSection("leftAfter", required: false)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="main-content-center float-left">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>

            </section>
```

My goal is to have the left menu with a fixed width and the right are that uses the remaining space. If screen-size is reduced the divs should move in order to have something like below, possibly all centered.

Any advice?

```
    ---------
    |       |
    |   1   |
    |       |
    |-------|
    |       |
    |   2   |
    |       |
    |-------|
    |       |
    |   3   |
    |       |
    ---------
```

Comment: Sincerely I was keeping it hidden in order to avoid misleading advices, but right now I am able to use float to obtain the desired functionality for divs 1 and 2 while 3 seems tied to float:left -> up float:right -> down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
    #div1, #div3 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
    #div2 {
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this...

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right top"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right bot"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {width: 85%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
.left {float: right; height: 510px; width: 49%; background: pink;}
.right {float: left; height: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 49%;}
.right.top {background: green;}
.right.bot {background: red;}
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .left, .right {float: none; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 200px;}
}
```

**Screenshots**

Above `600px`

[image]

Below `600px`

[image]

**Demo here:** [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oxoham/2)

Comment: Your elements look like they're in the wrong order.  The 2 smaller divs should appear on the left, and the larger one on the right.

Comment: OKay... Just a small change. :) Just change the `float: left` to `float: right` and vice-versa... Gimme a min and I will update the fiddle. *ps: Tough to take a screenshot again, please understand...*

Comment: Also, when the elements appear inline for narrower devices, the larger one (your pink one) is supposed to be in the middle.

Comment: Provided the OP is ok with the source order of the elements, looks good to me.

Comment: @Mauro Lemme know if this suits your requirement. :)

Comment: Your sense of right and left is ambidexterous ;-) Here's an example I built from "decoding" right and left. It displays inputs and a pink region.  http://jsfiddle.net/jNW8c/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media queries.

> A media query consists of a media type and at least one expression
>   that limits the style sheets' scope by using media features, such as
>   width, height, and color. Added in CSS3, media queries let the
>   presentation of content be tailored to a specific range of output
>   devices without having to change the content itself.

**example of a media query**

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* css */
}
```

this media query will execute when the screen is smaller than 500px;

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B2cKy/**

Comment: Dear Eric, please note that your answer is missing the main subject of the question that is moving a "left" div after the main div when resize happens. Please see edited question for a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

This code is highly imperfect, but it meets your requirements in terms of how the elements should be laid out.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uxTy/ (prefixes not included)

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</section>

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.a, .b {
    flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.c {
    flex: 2 0 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 20em) {
    .a, .b, .c {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .b {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

This is probably as close as you're going to be able to get to what you want without modifying your markup or compromising your design.  Flexbox does not have very widespread support at the moment, due to the fact that IE10 is the first IE to support it.

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Yeah... well, its good practice for when we can *finally* use it for actual layout purposes.

Comment: I love flexbox... But the problem is with the implementation, as it requires IE 10 and all the better modern browsers! :( Also the specification is changing from time to time! :(

Comment: Actually, the current spec is a Candidate Recommendation, so it shouldn't be changing much if at all.