# CSS: Reposition column based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

For my web project, I am using Bulma CSS to create a responsive web app. I'm not quite an expert with CSS as my background are strongly with iOS & Android. So I am trying to achieve this layout:

**1. Desktop**

All columns should have dynamic height based on it's content but the width of column 3 should remain at 30% of the viewport.

[image]

**2. Mobile**

All column should have dynamic height but the only difference being column 3 inserted in between column 1 & column 2. All column width should occupy 100% of the view port

[image]

**What I have tried so far**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<style>
  .column {
    height: 500px;
    background-color:purple;
    margin:2em;
    color: white;
    font-size:2em;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
  }
</style>

<div class="columns">
<div class="column"> 1 </div>
<div class="column"> 2 </div>
<div class="column"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

This is where I am stuck at. I followed through this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14961320/6699134) but it doesn't seem to support dynamic height based on it's content

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use Grid & Media queries:

**style.css:**

```
.columns {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 30%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
                    "col1 col3" 
                    "col2 col3";
}
.column {
    width: 100%;
}
.column1 {
    grid-area: col1;
}
.column2 {
    grid-area: col2;
}
.column3 {
    grid-area: col3;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .columns {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: none;
    }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column1 column">1</div>
    <div class="column2 column">2</div>
    <div class="column3 column">3</div>
</div>
```

You can easily find out about grid here -> [Grid Garden](https://codepip.com/games/grid-garden/)

And here about media queries -> [MDN Docs Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)